# "Wheel of Time", Perrin's PLOD

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I just came across this term, what does Perrin's PLOD mean? I'm guessing it's during the time he was single-mindedly tring to rescure Faile. But I'm still curious what the PLOD stands for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Plot Line of Doom

According to [this website](http://www.dragonmount.com/forums/topic/73107-most-headdesk-worthy-wot-couple/), yes, it does refer to the time he spent trying to rescue Faile.

It may have originated with Leigh Butler, in her WoT rereads. [For example](http://www.tor.com/2010/07/20/the-wheel-of-time-re-read-winters-heart-part-3/):

> And the Plotline of Doom officially kicks off. DUN.