# Where did Perrin get the letter from Suroth?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *Knife of Dreams*, Perrin negotiates a truce with a bunch of Seanchan, and he hands their leaders a letter from Suroth. (edits and emphasis mine)

> From his left gauntlet he pulled a folded, grease-stained piece of paper.
>
> Tylee's eyebrows rose as she read it. Perrin had the short text by heart. **The bearer of this stands under my personal protection. In the name of the Empress, may she live forever, give him whatever aid he requires in service to the Empire and speak of it to none but me**. He had no idea who Suroth Sabelle Meldarath was, but if she signed her name to something like that, she had to be important.

Where does he get this letter from? I don't recall Perrin being near any Seanchan before this, except in *The Great Hunt* at Falme, but he doesn't get any letter from any High Lady there as far as I remember. So, **when and where does Perrin get this letter?**

Comment: Just checked, and there are some [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WoT/comments/6k8r7j/spoilers_kodwhere_did_perrin_get/) [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/WoT/comments/1mwf3b/question_about_perrin_in_knife_of_dreams_spoiler/) that have pointed out that Perrin gets it from Masema, and I have reread (skimmed through) *Winter's Heart* as suggested, but my [PLOD](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128470/wheel-of-time-perrins-plod)-weary eyes can't find any mention of any letter. Could use some help with the exact quote and book this occurs in.

Comment: Wild, I just hit that spot in my re-read and was wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Perrin gets it from Berelain

It's *Crossroads of Twilight*, Chapter 6.

Shortly after Perrin discovers the Darkhound tracks, Berelain finds him and hands him a basket containing roast chicken and tells him,

> "I've had my thief-catchers nosing about in Masema's camp, making 'friends.'"
>
> [...]
>
> "I put something in that basket besides bread and a woodhen. A ... document ... that Santes found early yesterday, locked away in Masema's camp desk. [...] he should have memorized the thing without taking it, but what's done is done."

Perrin then eats his breakfast(?) and reads the note, which does indeed read as you cite.